# Built in capability for analytic functions to not be applied to first N rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wondering if there is any built in support for analytic functions to not be applied to the first **n**-rows of my SQL query.

Example code:

```
;with cte (num, dollar) as
(
    select 1, cast(1.45 as decimal(12,2))
    union all
    select num + 1, cast(dollar + 1.00 as decimal(12,2))
    from cte
    where num < 20
)
select cte.num, cte.dollar
    , avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 3 PRECEDING) as ThreeMonthAvg
    , avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 6 PRECEDING) as SixMonthAvg
from cte
```

Here I am getting a rolling three and six-month average of the dollar amount, respectively. This will obviously populate each row with a value for those columns relying on the analytic avg. However, since it isn't truly an average of the preceding three rows for rows 1 and 2, I want to display a 0, null, whatever works.

My current solution: uses a rownum either using `row_number()` in my actual setting or a recursively constructed row num here for the test case. Regardless, rather than a case-when statement.

```
--solution
;with cte (num, dollar) as
(
    select 1, cast(1.45 as decimal(12,2))
    union all
    select num + 1, cast(dollar + 1.00 as decimal(12,2))
    from cte
    where num < 20
)
select cte.num, cte.dollar
    , case when cte.num >= 3 then avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 3 PRECEDING) else 0 end as ThreeMonthAvg
    , case when cte.num >= 6 then avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 6 PRECEDING) else 0 end as SixMonthAvg
from cte
```

Is there a built in way to tell the function to "skip" applying the function the first 'n' rows, but not filter the row out of result set?

Checked Microsoft Docs and couldn't find anything myself supporting or denying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a built-in method, but this version works under more circumstances:

```
with cte (num, dollar) as (
      select 1, cast(1.45 as decimal(12,2))
      union all
      select num + 1, cast(dollar + 1.00 as decimal(12,2))
      from cte
      where num < 20
     )
select cte.num, cte.dollar,
       (case when count(*) over (order by cte.num ROWS 3 PRECEDING) = 3
             then avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 3 PRECEDING)
        end) as ThreeMonthAvg,
       (case when count(*) over (order by cte.num ROWS 6 PRECEDING) = 6
             then avg(cte.dollar) over (order by cte.num ROWS 6 PRECEDING)
        end) as SixMonthAvg
from cte;
```

This actually counts the rows going into the average, rather than depending on specific numeric values.